# What is the minimum number of Pokémon Go raids so that all friendships level up once?

Tags: graph-theory

We have $N$ players, all of whom are friends with eachother. Each friendship can level up once, whenever the two friends are in the same raid together. At most 20 people can be in a raid together, and a player can only be in one raid at a time.

What is the minimum number of raids to make all friendships level up?

Say any number of raids can be going on at once and that each raid takes unit time. What is the minimum amount of time to make all friendships level up?

Edit: This is a duplicate of this question:
[Algorithm for a group of people meeting each other person in the least amount of iterations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273270/algorithm-for-a-group-of-people-meeting-each-other-person-in-the-least-amount-of/273301#273301)

Comment: There are $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ friendship relations, and between $20$ people there are $\frac{20\cdot 19}2=190$ relations. So an immediate result is that it takes _at least_ $\frac{N(N-1)}{380}$ raids.

Comment: An upper bound is to split N into groups of at most 10, and do a raid for every possible pairwise matchup of such groups, i.e. at most $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ where $n = \lceil N/10 \rceil$

Comment: This is also an upper bound in terms of time, when $n = \lceil N / 10 \rceil$ the all-plays-all tournament of all $n$ groups can be done in $n/2$ time (conjecture) see that it holds for $n = 20$ here: http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/tournaments/all-play-all/apa_20.html

Comment: This is also of course the Set Cover problem where U is the N-complete graph and S is the set of all subsets of size 20 of U

Comment: See, these are the kind of things you ought to put into the question post itself. It is part of  what we call [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) and it is generally considered a prerequisite for a good question post. It makes it much easier for prospective answerers to know how advanced an answer ought to be, and helps them not tell you things you already know.

Comment: Ah, apologies I'm working these things out as I go. None of these are really a solid lead, though.