# How many meetings would it take for 12 people to meet in 4 groups of 3 until they met everyone?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have a group of 12 people that I would like to meet in four groups of three each month.  How many minimum months would it take such that each person has been in at least one group with every other person? Below is the brute force method I used to get it to seven months:

[image]

Comment: Consider the the combinations of 12 taken 3 district objects every time 12c3

Comment: My apologies you are correct.  For clarity, I would like them to meet in four groups of 3 each month.  Then how many months will it take until everyone is in a group with everyone else?  I have been able to get it to seven months by manually arranging, but I have not been able to prove if it could be done in six or even five months

Comment: Thanks for the link. That A) explains what you want to do, and B) serves as context showing that you have worked on this yourself. I expect the votes to close to subside :-)

Comment: It takes at least six months.  Each person has to meet eleven others and meets two people a month.  The question is whether you can avoid too much duplication so you need another month.

Comment: Thank you Ross.  I am now trying to see if you can avoid enough duplication to get it down to six months.

Comment: Are you sure it is for 7 months? I may be wrong, and I'll look really stupid if I am doing something wrong, but I can't find a random set like {2,7,9}.

Comment: I got 55 months by using the permutation equation. I will look really stupid if I am wrong but, using $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, I get 220 possible combinations, divided by 4 per month, I get 55 months? I am so sorry if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Sdavid552 You don't have to find all three people together. 2 has been with 7 and also with 9.Also 7 has been with 9. Any two numbers you pick should have come together together atleast once.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question then. I feel really stupid, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added a table to make it clearer.  It appears from Ross's comment that it has to be at least six months, but as you can see from my table I haven't been able to accomplish it in less than 7.  It is ok for people to meet together more than once on the path to getting people to meet each other in these groups of three.

Comment: Too bad you don't have 16 people meeting in groups of four. The we could use plane geometry over the field of four elements and do this perfectly in five months with no repetitions. The idea would be to have groups meeting on a given month come from parallel lines sharing the slope. The slope has five possible values (four from the field, and then the vertical lines with infinite slope). I wonder whether that can be tweaked to work with twelve? Like leaving the points on a line out of that picture, and somehow compensating for the month when the slope of that line would be used.

Comment: (cont'd) With that idea we could do this in five months (without repetitions), if on the last month there would be three meetings with four people in each (instead of the dictated four meetings with three in each). Obviously we cannot do better than six months with the existing rules :-)

Comment: Nope. After following that scheme for four months, the not-yet-met people are split into four groups of four. And you cannot arrange all them to meet in two meetings. Need a different approach. Sorry about thinking aloud.

Comment: Jyrki - Thank you I like that idea.  Can you do in six months?  I cannot find the combination that makes that work.

Comment: @Sdavid552 - I had the same issue. In fact, the way the problem is stated, with  "all 12 people had been in a group together",  the answer is "never" as each group only contains 3 people. :--) The OP should probably edit the problem to use the condition "each person has been in at least one group with every other person".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC , I am glad. On another notice, after a few hours, I am surprised that no-one has solved this problem. I'll check it out again later if no-one has solved it by then.

Comment: Thank you for this edit and clarity.  This is exactly what I am trying to determine.

Comment: @Sdavid552- I think it's because it doesn't have a "nice" solution; it's like splitting 59 Xmas cookies into bags -- you're going to have some leftovers and it's hard to account for raggedy edges.

Comment: There are ${12 \choose 2} = 66$ couples to occur in $6$ months, i.e. in $6 \cdot 4 = 24$ groups. Let $x_3$ be the number of groups in which $3$ couples appear for the first time, $x_2$ and $x_1$ similarly for $2$ and $1$ ($0$ cannot be). We have $3x_3+2x_2+x_1=66$ and $x_3+x_2+x_1=24$ and subtracting from the first $2x_3+x_2=42$. Suppose $x_3 \lt 18$ then $18+x_3+x_2>42$ i.e. $x_3+x_2>24$, impossible. Therefore it must be $x_3 \ge 18$. This looks impossible to do (we should be able to make more than $4$ months with all new couples), although I am not able to prove it.

Comment: Some keyphrases that might lead somewhere: social golfer problem. Combinatorial designs.

Comment: The social golfer hint led to [OEIS A107431](https://oeis.org/A107431) and then [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20050308115423/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/~wh/golf/) and, for $12$ players never staying in the same group of $3$ as any other player twice [a solution with 4 rounds](http://web.archive.org/web/20050407074608/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/~wh/golf/solutions.html#4-3-4), which then I completed manually to get a near solution to the OP problem in $6$ months:

Comment: ... a near solution to the OP problem in $6$ months (only $5$ and $7$ never meet :-)): $((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)), ((1,4,7),(2,5,10),(3,8,11),(6,9,12)),((1,9,10),(2,4,8),(3,5,12),(6,7,11)),((1,5,11),(2,7,12),(3,4,9),(6,8,10)),((1,8,12),(2,9,11),(3,6,7),(4,5,10)),((1,2,6),(3,10,7),(4,11,12),(5,8,9))$

Comment: @BillyJoe It is impossible to have a solution in 6 months if you continue from the 4 round solution. To see why, observe a graph whose vertices are $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$. Draw edges between vertices that haven't yet met. If you continue from the 4 round solution, then the graph has: 3 cycles $\{1,8,12\},\{3,7,10\},\{2,9,11\}$; and $6$ is connected to $1,2,3$; and $5$ is connected to $7,8,9$; and $4$ is connected to $10,11,12$. That is, we have $18$ edges. If you do not remove any cycles using 5,6 months, then you can remove at most $16$ edges. Otherwise, the best you can do is your near solution.

Comment: @Vepir then if my other comment (regarding the number of triplets making one, two or three new couples) is correct, there must be $4$ "full" months to complete in $6$ months, therefore completing in $6$ months is not possible. Am I right?

Comment: @BillyJoe If the 4 round solution is unique up to symmetry, then we've concluded that $x_3\ge 18$ is not possible if first $16$ out of the $x_3$ groups are in first 4 months. But why must this be the case? That is, what rules out spreading $x_3$ groups across all 6 months?

Comment: There is a similar problem [Algorithm for a group of people meeting each other person in the least amount of iterations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273270/318073). E.g. it is possible to spread $12$ people across $4\cdot 6=24$ groups, but it is not clear if it is possible to separate those $24$ groups into $6$ months such that all $4$ groups in every month are disjoint.

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this *set covering* problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each of the $\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}/4!=15400$ possible groupings $g\in G$ of 12 people into 4 groups of 3, let binary decision variable $x_g$ indicate whether that grouping is used.  For each pair $(i,j)$ of people with $i<j$, let $G_{i,j} \subset G$ be the set of groupings that cover that pair.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{g \in G} x_g$ subject to
$$\sum_{g \in G_{i,j}} x_g \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $i<j$}$$
The minimum turns out to be 7.

Comment: What software did you use to solve this problem?  I tried a straightforward solution with Google's CP-SAT solver, where I specified the first set of meetings, and it's been running for a day and a half.  I'm using the python version, but I don't think that should matter, since since it takes an eye blink to set up the model, and I presume the optimizer itself is compiled C++ or C code.

Comment: I used the [MILP solver in SAS](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_008&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_milpsolver_toc.htm&docsetVersion=v_002&locale=en), and it took less than a minute.  This problem is highly symmetric, and a solver that doesn't exploit that will do a lot of redundant work.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I couldn't figure out how to exploit the symmetry except by specifying the first meeting.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to SAS.  Do you know of any free software that would do a creditable job on this problem?  (Or do I just need to learn to use the Google tool appropriately?)