# A division of $4$ groups with the condition that everyone will get a chance to get to know everybody else

Tags: combinatorics

My friend wants to separate $26$ people into $4$ groups. Each group will attend a week long trip together with $4$ weeks available so $4$ trips in total. So the question is how could we split up and rotate the people such that everyone sees everybody else in at least one of those trips. We would like everyone to get a chance to get to know everybody else and have $4$ supervisors hence the division.

I'm new to combinatorics and struggle to help. I'm not even sure if this is possible to do. Do you have any suggestions?

**Edit:** We would like to have every kid to have an opportunity to meet every other kid, but if the group sizes are to uneven it breaks the point of the group separation. That means that $2$ groups with $8$ people and $2$ with $5$ is still ok but if we have one group with $23$ then what use are $4$ supervisors. If you tell me the goal cannot be met that would be ok too and we'd make concessions. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any limits on the size of each group?

Comment: We would like a more or less equal distribution to make it easy for the supervisors. If one supervisor has 20 kids and the others share the rest that would be unfortunate

Comment: I hope that people do not vote to close this question, as it is asked well and context is provided. However, it would be helpful if you provided a more specific upper limit on the group size. The goals of "everyone meets everyone" and "the supervisors have almost equal distribution" are opposed to each other, so you should make it clear which is more important by editing that into your post. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: I have updated the question in the hope to clarify and as I said above, if it cannot be solved by now I'd just be happy to know that.

Comment: Each week every kid will meet an average of $\frac{26}{4}-1$ other kids and an average of $22 \lt 25$ people in the $4$ weeks. Therefore, unless accepting that some couple may never meet, we need at least $5$ weeks. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958398/573047).